# Magnific Popup plugin: Preloader not working on iframe

Tags: magnific-popup

I used the plugin to open up an internal page, which works fine with iframe but the preloader does not show up. I just want to display a preloader image or a "loading..." text. This is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').magnificPopup({type:'iframe', preload: true});
});
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Javascript source of jquery.magnific-popup.js, the mfp.updateStatus('loading'); is never called in the iFrame code block. So what I did was simply add mfp.updateStatus('loading'); to the initIframe function and remove mfp.updateStatus('ready'); from the getIframe function. It may be better to add a setTimeout to call the mfp.updateStatus('ready') but it seems to work okay without that.

Comment: Sorry to reply after a long time. I tried your solution but it did not work for me. Do I need to add `mfp.updateStatus('loading');` at any specific location inside `initIframe` function?

Comment: Actually... your solution works! :) I just found that the background colour of `.mfp-iframe-scaler iframe` needs to be made transparent if it's not already transparent: `.mfp-iframe-scaler iframe { background-color:transparent!important; }`.Thanks.